# Does Android application memory limit apply to entire app or per process of app?

Tags: java, android

I am having an issue hitting the memory limit of my application. My question is if I break my application into a few processes will this allow each process to get a 24mb limit or will all processes add up to hit the 24mb limit?

Comment: I'd try writing a small app that forks off some processes.  That should answer your question.  "Don't guess, measure it. Don't theorize, try it."  Two maxims I put on my cube wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Android follows Oracle's heap space guidelines for Java, it says: "Maximum heap size depends on maximum address space per *process*." [Tuning The Java Heap](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19900-01/819-4742/abeii/index.html)

If you are able to break your application into a few process, you might be able to get more than 24MB.. The only thing I can see not letting you do this would be an Android security feature to prevent malicious application from forkbombing the phone..

Here is an article by Matt Clark about good programming habits to be efficient with your 24MB of heap space.. [Developing Apps Within Android's 16MB Memory Limit](http://blog.gorges.us/2010/07/developing-apps-within-androids-16mb-memory-limit/)

Hope this helps, good luck!